# Read (GEO)JSON file from web service using FME Desktop

Tags: geojson, fme-form

I have a webmap of bike stations and there is a json service for these stations behind the map.

Is it possible to provide this URL as the source dataset, using FME Desktop?

Does FME Desktop support real-time data applications?

I need to be able to access the URL and write a workbench that would capture the bike station status in 5 minutes increments and put the results in a .csv ot .txt file.

Any ideas?

Comment: changed tag from json to GeoJSON

Comment: GeoJSON is formatted different to JSON http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_ReadersWriters/FME_Readers_Writers.htm#geojson/Overview.htm use this reader in FME

Answer (score 3):

Here is an older workspace reading json from our google geocoder (we have enterprise license to do this).

The process is simple it sends a request out to the service [most api's will return json or xml] which returns the json file which then will be processed and reformatted

Note:we had to use a [decelerator](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/decelerator.htm) transformer because FME was processing the inputs too fast to the api service (blocks if too fast)
0.5 second delay worked for get the responses back.

[image]

Update you need a creator first with a Null value (you populate this later)

httpcaller (fetcher) is the json file your are calling from the web

JSONfragmentor (exploder) will get the json info

You will need to break the response up into attributes then you can create points, lines, polygons from the data you have extracted.

this is the file it is retrieving in json format

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=41.88,-87.62&destination=29.75,-95.36&sensor=true&mode=driving

[image]

**Update2** your data is in GeoJSON (not json) use the GeoJSON reader in FME 2015
like this
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still don't understand what goes into the HTTPFletcher, since I need to specify the source URL inside this transformer.  What do I need to link HTTP Fletcher  from? Thanks

Comment: see the update above based on you comments need to have a creator first then request the json from the web as GET request

Comment: Thank you very much Mapperz, I have an idea now, even if I'm getting an error...but, I am sure can figure it out myself :) Thanks

Comment: I installed the FME 2015 version and still getting HTTPCaller <Rejected> and have no idea why.This is the file it is retrieving the json: http://www.rideindego.com/stations/json/

Comment: use the GeoJSON reader - I read in 71 features in the Philadelphia area. see update 2

Comment: Thanks a lot! For some reason, I am not able to add the GeoJSON reader to my page. I select the format, enter the URL and get this: "Trying to find a DYNAMIC plugin for reader named `GEOJSON'
Loaded module 'GEOJSON' from file 'C:\Program Files\FME\plugins/JSON.dll'
FME API version of module 'GEOJSON' matches current internal version (3.7 20141021)
Opening the GEOJSON reader with source dataset 'http://www.rideindego.com/stations/json'
A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details"

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. I had a proxy set on my system, but I was able to open the url in my web browser. In the FME Options, I selected "Use system proxy settings" instead of "No Proxy". It works now. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As for the automation part - "5 minutes increments" - that's usually what FME Server is used for. However, you could use a [tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software) or script of some sort to simply run your workspace from the command line at set intervals (or a cron command if you're on on linux)

When you run the workspace in Workbench, the very top lines of the log window will tell you what the command will be to run the workspace on the command line.

Comment: I followed the structure suggested by Mapperz, but I'm still getting an error saying: "JSONFragmenter: A JSON syntax error was found at line 1. The JSON data is incomplete: Unexpectedly encountered the end of JSON data." For the automation part, we don't have FME Server, but we will in a few weeks, the Server and the Cloud. Thank you for your suggestion to run my workbench from the command line, I can try Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: use the GeoJSON reader - I read in 71 features in the Philadelphia area.